# Angular JS sorting and converting strings to integers

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm currently facing and issue here which I cant seem to get around. I have a json that contains an array of people and inside each person its another array of strings. In the array I have numbers and actual string values. The integers themselves are being treated as strings so when I use orderby it sorts incorrectly because it thinks the integers are strings.

What I am trying to figure out is of a way I can convert the strings to integers as I am using ng-repeat to spit out the integers.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="TableCtrl">
    <p><strong>Page:</strong> {{tableParams.page()}}</p>
        <p><strong>Count per page:</strong> {{tableParams.count()}}</p>
    <table ng-table="tableParams">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'0'">{{person[0]}} {{person[1]}}</td>
        <td data-title="'Age'" sortable="'2'">{{ person[2] }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Current JSON structure:

```
0: Array[3]
0: "John"
1: "Doe"
2: "25"
```

My javascript:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('TableCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngTableParams', '$filter',

        function($scope, $http, ngTableParams, $filter) {
            $scope.People= {};
            $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1, // show first page
                count: 10 // count per page
            }, {
                total: 0, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: "json.url.json"
                    })
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                            $scope.tableParams.total(data.length)

                            $scope.People= data;

                            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) :
                                data;

                            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
                        })
                        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            // something went wrong :(
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
```

Currently using http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/ to try and execute the table and sorting functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I normally just do some preprocessing on the data as it comes in to create fields that are able to be sorted, etc.

```
angular.forEach(data,function(el,i){
  el.age_int = parseInt(el.age);
});

$scope.people = data;
```

Then you can use the new field for sorting or anything that requires integers over strings.